# webpack linux resolve path

Tags: linux, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack with react, I have Index.js file in Administrator folder

I can import without includes Index in path in Mac and windows

```
import Admin from '../components/Administrator/'
```

but when I call webpack in Linux ,it can't resolve file, but after I change it to

```
import Admin from '../components/Administrator/Index'
```

and it works.

I would like to fix this issue without adding Index in path as our colleges use Mac and Windows. if they forgot to add that, the code will broken in production, Does any one know what's the reason?

Comment: Case sensitivity filenames might be an issue since MacOS is not case-sensitive, wherease Linux is. Check whether the issue gets resolved by renaming Index.js to index.js.

Comment: I believe, webpack resolves a directory/module path by appending the `main` field in `package.json`. By default, its value is `index.js`

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

Comment: Can use some plugin to catch them at build time https://github.com/dcousineau/force-case-sensitivity-webpack-plugin

Comment: it's very help,thanks!